# Can I control audio/vibrate/DND on iOS remotely?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, remote-control, sound-volume

I have 2 iPad minis and an iPhone 6+.

Sometimes I like to hear the "ding" of a message or mail, sometimes I dont.  Its a pain to go to each device to change the settings.  Is it possible to set a remote iOS device to DND or turn the volume/vibrate/DND on/off from another device?

FYI, I do not have a Mac, just Windows or Linux.

Comment: Sounds like a automator action. Did you try it ?

Comment: @Buscar웃SD not familiar with that

Answer (score 1):

No. Per [iDownloadBlog.com's article on using "Do Not Disturb" in OS X Yosemite](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCMQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.idownloadblog.com%2F2014%2F10%2F25%2Fusing-do-not-disturb-in-os-x-yosemites-messages-app%2F&ei=rRSWVYmLEY3VoATdwIrgCw&usg=AFQjCNGAC4u-lYD2ExV41ZvG-SQlfkh5hQ&sig2=BDZ_Q5rV0ses-5jaDXMmYg&bvm=bv.96952980,d.cGU):

```
Do Not Disturb settings do not sync across the Mac and iOS devices.
```